# Creating python plugin in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

While I am learning to create a python plugin in QGIS 2.4.0, I have followed the procedure explained in "https://qgis.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/13_plugins.html#developing-plugins".

When I initiated QGIS, and opened the Plugin manager, it says under the "Invalid" tab,

***This plugin is incompatible with this version of QGIS
Plugin designed for QGIS 1.8 - 1.9
This plugin is experimental
HelloWorld
This is a plugin for greeting the (going multiline) world***

Can anybody help in describing the correct procedure?

Answer (score 2):

On 2.4 to recent versions, you can use the Plugin builder to help making a basic structure: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/pluginbuilder/

It seems the minimum QGIS version is 2.0 so it should work even on an old version.

However, i guess after QGIS gets to 3, there might be some compatibility problems.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to follow these steps:
http://anitagraser.com/2014/04/26/getting-started-writing-qgis-2-x-plugins/
With this combination of Winpython, Plugin-Builder and Plugin-Reloader you should be able to get a good basic Plugin to fill with the functionality you are trying to implement.